# Recurring linux process consuming cpu

Tags: server, cpu-usage, opensuse

On my opensuse server, I keep seeing this process coming up.
I've tried kill -9 and it comes back with a new process id within 30 seconds.
htop lists it as "bash", while top lists it as "xs".
The attached screenshot is what I could get from ps.
It stays after multiple reboots.
It doesn't seem like a normal zombie process to me.

Wondering if anyone has any advice?

Thanks

[ps info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvwdx.png)

Comment: You can use strace to checkout what it is doing, try to check open files with `strace -e open -p <PID>`. You can also use lsof to get opened files and connections. If is a _bash_ and is taking CPU it should be executing another children processes, try to look its child processes by running `ps -efH` and locating who is below it in the process tree. `pmap` command can show you shared libraries and other stuff loaded in memory. Good luck

Comment: Thanks for the advice, turns out I somehow got some mining malware. Looking up ways to remove it now.

Comment: Take care of your private keys, if they were compromised you will need to recreate them and remove from `.authorized_keys` at another hosts.